# What does it means- "'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."?

Tags: css, sass, command-prompt

I am running this on the command prompt - sass --watch variables.scss:variables.css
but getting this- "'sass' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
What does it means?
Also, how can convert scss file to css using the command I am using, or what's going wrong here?

Comment: It most likely means your dependency tree doesn't contain a reference to `sass`, so you should try installing it again with `npm install -g sass` just to make sure your project has the software installed then verify if the `sass` command is recognized.

Comment: So, before installing using the method you told, should I delete the one which I installed?